# How to join two tables and show them in one listview?

Tags: sql, winforms, sqlite, listview

I am using list-view that has it column form two different db tables .Here is my code that i am trying :

```
try
{
   String Query = "select id,Code,Description,Rate,Bottles,Supply,Empty,Amount,Received,
        Customer_New.Opening_Date,Customer_New.Clients_Title,Customer_New.Cust_Id 
         from (Items INNER JOIN Customer_New on Customer_New.Cust_Id=Items.Cust_Id)
                ,Customer_New";
    SQLiteDataAdapter  dba = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
    DataSet testDs = new DataSet();
    dba.Fill(testDs, "Items");    //error
    dba.Fill(testDs, "Customer_New");   //error
    DataTable dt = testDs.Tables[0];
    this.lvcmodify.DataContext = testDs.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    lvcmodify.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    testDs.Dispose();
    dba.Dispose();
    dt.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Does anyone knows how i can accomplish this functionality in list view ? .

Is it possible in sqlite to merge two table into logical tables at run-time with any change in db so that i can use that single table in command: dba.Fill(testDs, "Items");? 
Please help me to correct this code.Thanks

Comment: Can i use here dataTable.Merge() method ? If yes then how i can implement it in this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking you source code, I think the problem is your sql include Customer_New two times

Just remove last Customer_New table.

```
try
{
    Query = "select id,Code,Description,Rate,Bottles,Supply,Empty,Amount,Received,
       Customer_New.Opening_Date,Customer_New.Clients_Title,Customer_New.Cust_Id 
         from Items INNER JOIN Customer_New on Customer_New.Cust_Id=Items.Cust_Id";
    dba = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
    testDs = new DataSet();
    dba.Fill(testDs, "Items");
...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: query for creating view is not working in sqlite database ...In-spite of fact that my foreign key option is on

Comment: Error is :SQLiteManager: CREATE  VIEW  IF NOT EXISTS "main"."items_v" AS select id,Code,Description,Rate,Bottles,Supply,Empty,Amount,Received,
        Customer_New.Opening_Date as Opening_Date,Customer_New.Clients_Title as Clients_Title,Customer_New.Cust_Id as Cust_Id 
         from (Items INNER JOIN Customer_New on Customer_New.Cust_Id=Items.Cust_Id)
                ,Customer_New [ ambiguous column name: Customer_New.Opening_Date ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: Please post the error for your first query, I think problem in your query instead of fill function.

Comment: 1st Query Error: SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: create view items_v as
select id,Code,Description,Rate,Bottles,Supply,Empty,Amount,Received,
        Customer_New.Opening_Date as Opening_Date,Customer_New.Clients_Title as Clients_Title,Customer_New.Cust_Id as Cust_Id 
         from (Items INNER JOIN Customer_New on Customer_New.Cust_Id=Items.Cust_Id)
                ,Customer_New [ ambiguous column name:  Customer_New.Opening_Date ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: again same error at same point  ............ [ ambiguous column name: Customer_New.Opening_Date ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: Ok, just try to change Opening_Date to new name such as Opening_Date1. ==> Customer_New.Opening_Date as Opening_Date1. Do samething for Client_Title and Cust_ID.

Comment: i have remove that Customer_New.Opening_Date from query ..then error is .....Customer_New [ ambiguous column name: Customer_New.Clients_Title ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: and it i use this query then view is created successfully :...............create view items_v as
select tmp.id,tmp.Code,tmp.Description,tmp.Rate,tmp.Bottles,tmp.Supply,tmp.Empty,tmp.Amount,tmp.Received
       from (Items INNER JOIN Customer_New on Customer_New.Cust_Id=Items.Cust_Id) tmp
                ,Customer_New

Comment: What is status now? is the problem fixed? if not please contact me via skype fsoft_cuongvt